# Как в терминальном сеансе указать путь к другому диску?

Tags: python, windows

В терменале указан путь C:\Users\User>
как его изменить или указать другой. Хочу обновить пип. Питон установлен не на диске С, а на диске Д.

Answer (score 3):

В вашем случае поможет команда `cd` (расшифровка : Change Directory) в терминале  и после команды указываете путь, например:

```
D:
cd D:\(ваш путь)
```